# How come Splasher will not open on leaflet map?

Tags: jquery, html, button, maps, leaflet

Hello everybody I need some assistance please.

I made a splasher that is supposed to open over my leaflet map according to a tutorial I have been following. However it only opens above or below it. The splasher should just says a few words, and will potentially make a compelling point. Once they click the splasher it should close slowly, and open when they click button 2 on my html page which it does for me now. The splasher just will not open on the map. The splashe opens behind it, thus you cannot see the splasher or the text.

Here is the tutorial I used on youtube:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YRir-Hq4x4c

Here is my code, this is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> Map Elements Design jQuery</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet"       href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.css" >
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
<div id="header">
<h1 id="designTime">Design Time</h1>
<button id="button1" class="buttons">Button 1</button>
<button id="button2" class="buttons">Button 2</button>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="splasher"><h1>Is Eric Really Excelling?</h1><p1>Yes, he really  is</p1></div>
</div>



<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jqueryui.js"></script> 
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="js/ttc.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script> 


</body>


</html>
```

Here is my script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#splasher").click(function(){
        $("#splasher").fadeOut('slow');
    });
    $("#button2").click(function(){
        $("#splasher").fadeIn('slow');
    });

    var map = L.map('map',{
        center: [43.6577, -79.3788],
        zoom: 11,
        minzoom: 4,
        maxzoom: 14, 
        attributionControl: false
    });

    var firstLayer = 
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.stamen.com/watercolor/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg', {
attribution: 'Acetate tileset from GeoIQ'
})
    .addTo(map);

function attach (feature,layer) {
    layer.bindPopup("<h1 class='infoHeader'> Toronto TTC Subway Name</h1><p class='infoHeader'>" + feature.properties.SBWAY_NAME +"</p>");
};

    L.geoJSON(ttc,{

        onEachFeature: attach

}).addTo(map);

});
```

Here is my Style.css

```
html {
    background-color:gray;
}

body {
    width: 960px;
    padding: 5px;
    padding:5 px;
    font-family: "Indie Flower", "Fjalla One", Helvetica, Corbel;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: black;

}


#designTime {
    color: white;
    font-size: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    position: center;

}

#wrapper {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 100%;

}

#splasher {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    width: 500px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    opacity: .8;
    position: absolute;
    top: 250px;

}

#map {
    height: 580px;
    background-color:blue; 
}
```

Thank you kindly, your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be the versions, to fix this add z-index in your css

```
#splasher {
background-color: white;
padding: 16px;
padding-top: 0px;
width: 500px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
opacity: .8;
position: absolute;
top: 250px;
z-index:2000
}
```

You can check your project running here:
https://jsfiddle.net/cyjmv2rz/

and the second problem is `$("#splasher").click(function(){` change to `$("#button1").click(function(){`

Good lucky and good studies.

Comment: Thank you for your time. worked like a charm to disappear and re-appear the splasher using only the buttons. However I was aiming to make the splasher disapear when I click on it, and re-appear when I click one of the two buttons. Do you have a solution?

Comment: I wrote the solution for this too no? you just need to change a piece of your js code...